# Excel Formula for 3 conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match, sumifs

I need some help with creating a formula with three conditions. The answer should be 1 if at least one in the column has a tag of 1, otherwise 0. But if the cell “apple” is not on the list, we tag them as N/A.

I used the following formula, but it only applies for the tagging of 1 and 0. But some cell “apple” is not on the list so it should be tag as N/A.

```
=IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!U:U,Sheet1!B:B,A1)>=1,1,0)
```

Comment: Show some copiable sample data with expected output.

Comment: You used only one condition to `SUMIFS()`. Use more two conditions.

Comment: If you can provide a photo of what this currently looks like, I believe the answer might be as simple as 3 nested if statements. Attach a photo so we can give you some help!